# Unable to display foreign key attribute on a django app

Tags: python, django

I have two models in my db.
They are:-

- Modules
- Topics

Topics is a foreign key of Modules.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Modules(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Topics(models.Model):
    modules = models.ForeignKey(Modules,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Here is my HTML code:-

```
{% extends "algorithms/header.html" %}

{% block content %}  
{% if all_topics %}  
    <div class="row">
      {% for topic in modules.topics_set.all %}
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card cyan lighten-4">
          <div class="card-content black-text">
            <span class="card-title"><b>{{ topic.name }}</b></span>            <p>{{topic.algorithm_content|safe}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="/algorithms/{{ module_name }}/{{ topic.name }}/">View</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% else %}
  <h3>The admin has not uploaded any courses yet</h3>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my views.py
all_topics contains all the Topics in the db.

```
#Import Dependencies
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from .models import Modules,Topics
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    all_modules = Modules.objects.all()
    html = ''
    context = {
        'all_modules':all_modules,
    }
    return render(request,'algorithms/home.html',context)

def topic(request,module_name):
    print(module_name)
    all_topics = Topics.objects.all()
    all_modules = Modules.objects.all()
    try:
        module = Modules.objects.get(name=module_name)
    except Modules.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Module does not exist.")
    context = {
        'all_topics' : all_topics,
        'module_name' : module_name
    }
    return render(request,'algorithms/topic.html',context)
```

I am unable to see any data of 'Topics' model.

Comment: You need to show your view. What are `all_topics` and `modules`? And *exactly* what do you actually see?

Comment: all_topics is the context part containing all the topics in the db. I see nothing on the page.Also, all_topics is for later part in the code.So please ignore it!

Comment: `modules` is the foreignkey reference I created in the models.py

Comment: No it isn't. You're using `modules` as a standalone variable, and you're using `all_topics` as a boolean which will potentially hide the entire for loop. So *you need to show your view*.

Comment: ohk, just a second

Comment: @DanielRoseman added the views.py

Comment: Well now you've posted two views. Which is the relevant one? Note that neither of them define both `all_topics` and `modules`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman check the topic function please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with foreign keys. It's to do with a complete lack of consistency in naming between views and templates.

Your `topic` view sends two things to the template: `all_topics`, which is a list of all Topics items in the db, and `module_name`, which is simply a string. The two other things that are defined in that view - `all_modules` and `module` - are simply thrown away. (Note that the even view itself appears to be misnamed, since it is querying Modules, not Topics.)

Then, in the view, you have an `if` condition on `all_topics`, but then within that block you try and loop over `modules.topics_set.all`. But `modules` is never defined; it's certainly not ever sent to the template, but there isn't even a variable by that name in the view.

Perhaps what you meant to do was to define a `module` view which sends a specific module to the template, and then to iterate over that? If so, that is what you should do.

```
def module(request, module_name):
    all_topics = Topics.objects.all()
    try:
        module = Modules.objects.get(name=module_name)
    except Modules.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Module does not exist.")
    context = {
        'all_topics': all_topics,
        'module': module
    }
    return render(request,'algorithms/topic.html', context)
```

and then in the template, iterate directly over that:

```
{% block content %}  
    <div class="row">
      {% for topic in module.topics_set.all %}
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card cyan lighten-4">
          <div class="card-content black-text">
            <span class="card-title"><b>{{ topic.name }}</b></span>
            <p>{{topic.algorithm_content|safe}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="/algorithms/{{ module_name }}/{{ topic.name }}/">View</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  {% empty %}
    <h3>The admin has not uploaded any courses yet</h3>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Note the change from `modules` to `module`, and the use of `for...empty` instead of the `if`.